# Send email directly from application without opening chooser (Kotlin)

Tags: email, kotlin, android-intent

I need to be able to send user data from my app directly to email without opening the app chooser. Basically. I need the user to be able to grant permission for the emails to be sent (in the same way as they have to grant send SMS permission) and then each time they add data to various fields and click the submit button, it then sends the content of their entries to a designated email address. createChooser I assume is calling the app chooser, but I cant work out how I can do it without it?  Existing example code below. I cannot find a direct answer to this anywhere and any help greatly appreciated.

```
     val gasb: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.gasb)
     gasb.setOnClickListener {
     val data:String = "1 GAS BOTTLE USED "
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(getEmailIntent("firstname.surname@email.com", "SUBJECT", 
    data), 
    "Send mail"))
    }

    }

    //The below works - Just need to work out how to send without opening email client
    private fun getEmailIntent(email: String, subject: String?, content: String?): Intent? {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "message/rfc822"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(email))
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content)
    return getIntent(intent, true)
    }
    private fun getIntent(intent: Intent, isNewTask: Boolean): Intent? {
    return if (isNewTask) intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) else intent

    }
    }
```

Comment: You can't send emails from background without the notice of a user

Comment: Do you have the email and password of the user? If it was possible otherwise, it would be a *major* security issue.

Comment: OK, I am doing this with SMS without opening the messaging app. Yes, I can get the email and password of the user as this is an app for my work phones.